# Package keyval Error: pdfa undefined

Tags: errors

I try to compile a friends project and get the following error message:

```
! Package keyval Error: pdfa undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.2238 \ProcessKeyvalOptions{Hyp}
```

In this project there is no line 2238 and the package `keyval` is not used either.

Same project can be compiled on other machines.

This happens when I use the package `jheppub`, so a minimal working example would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{jheppub}
```

Comment: A minimal example producing the error is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Package `hyperref` has introduced option `pdfa` in version 2008/04/19 v6.77r. If your `hyperref` version is older, then an update is needed to get the option.